# Can I create a transaction using API from two different addresses?

Tags: node.js, api, solidity

I am trying to use site A to call a send function to send a request to site B's API. I want site B's API to create a transaction that sends Ether to a predefined address, and return a Metamask popup to the user on site A to confirm or reject the transaction. Is it possible to create a transaction using API from two different addresses?

site a after pressing send button will call site api b with path /send and create transaction, i get error can't complete

`app.post('/send', (req, res) => {
const address = req.body.address;
console.log(address);

const userAddress = address;

const toAddress = '0xf197c6c';
const txObject = {
from: userAddress,
to: toAddress,
value: web3.utils.toWei('0', 'ether')
};`

Comment: where is your [mcve]?